# Scrapy not following next page

Tags: python, scrapy, pagination

I'm sitting on this problem for quite some time now but everything that i try is not working.
My goal is to simply extract data from a job offering website. On each site, 20 jobs are offered. I'm extracting data of each offer using scrapy callback. That works more or less. The problem is scrapy does not jump on the next page, no matter what I try. I first tried scrapy & selenium, does not work. Now I try it only with scrapy and followed tutorials, but it still only extracts data from the first 20 offers on page 1.

Important: The next button changes througout the pages, which means its xpath/css selector changes. I tried css last-nth-child and xpath last()-1 but no satisfying result. What makes it even more difficult, after the variable xpath element a a tag follows with the link in it.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class WorkpoolJobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'getdata'
allowed_domains = ['workpool-jobs.ch']
start_urls = ['https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs']

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = "//p[@class='inserattitel h2 mt-0']/a/@href"
    for joboffer in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR):
        url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.get())
        yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

    next_page = response.xpath(".//li[@class='page-item'][last()-1]/../@href").get()
    wait(randint(5,10))
    if next_page:
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    single_info = response.xpath(".//*[@class='col-12 col-md mr-md-3 mr-xl-5']")

    for info in single_info:
        info_Titel = info.xpath(".//article/h1[@class='inserattitel']/text()").extract_first()
        info_Berufsfelder = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-top-grau']/p/text()").extract()
        info_Arbeitspensum = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[1]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Anstellungsverhältnis = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[2]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Arbeitsort = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[4]/a/text()").extract()
        info_VerfügbarAb = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[5]/text()").extract()
        info_Kompetenzenqualifikation = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7']/dl[2]/dd/text()").extract_first()
        info_Aufgabengebiet = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]//*[self::p or self::li]").extract()
        info_Erwartungen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][2]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_WirBietenIhnen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][3]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_Publikationsdatum = info.xpath(".//article/footer[@class='inseratfooter']/p[1]/strong/text()").extract_first()

        yield {'Titel': info_Titel,
        'Berufsfelder': info_Berufsfelder,
        'Arbeitspensum': info_Arbeitspensum,
        'Anstellungsverhältnis': info_Anstellungsverhältnis,
        'Arbeitsort': info_Arbeitsort,
        'VerfügbarAb': info_VerfügbarAb,
        'Kompetenzenqualifikation': info_Kompetenzenqualifikation,
        'Aufgabengebiet': info_Aufgabengebiet,
        'Erwartungen': info_Erwartungen,
        'WirBietenIhnen': info_WirBietenIhnen,
        'Publikationsdatum': info_Publikationsdatum}
```

Any help is so much appreciated!

Comment: maybe you should search by text in link - ie `.//a[text()="nächste"]/@href` or `.//a[contains(text(), "nächste")]/@href` or `.//a[@title="nächste Seite anzeigen"]/@href`. Eventually you could generate link manually  - it seems it looks like `/recht-jobs?seite=2` so you could use `"/recht-jobs?seite=" + str(number)` and use `number += 1`

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at it. Hopefully that finally works out :)

Comment: It finally worked!! I tried all your suggestions but with some youtube videos and the "manual" link generation it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: by the way: I get link to next page using `response.xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'nächste')]/@href").get()` but manual version let you better control how many pages you want to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

With some hints form furas, I finally managed to make my code working. If anyone has the same problem in the future, maybe my code below helps you as well:

```
import scrapy
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class WorkpoolJobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "getdata"
page_number = 2
allowed_domains = ["workpool-jobs.ch"]
start_urls = ["https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs"]

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = "//p[@class='inserattitel h2 mt-0']/a/@href"
    for joboffer in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR):
        url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.get())
        yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

    next_page = "https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs?seite=" + str(WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number)
    sleep(randint(5,10))
    if WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number < 27:
        WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number += 1
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    single_info = response.xpath(".//*[@class='col-12 col-md mr-md-3 mr-xl-5']")

    for info in single_info:
        info_Titel = info.xpath(".//article/h1[@class='inserattitel']/text()").extract_first()
        info_Berufsfelder = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-top-grau']/p/text()").extract()
        info_Arbeitspensum = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[1]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Anstellungsverhältnis = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[2]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Arbeitsort = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[4]/a/text()").extract()
        info_VerfügbarAb = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[5]/text()").extract()
        info_Kompetenzenqualifikation = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7']/dl[2]/dd/text()").extract_first()
        info_Aufgabengebiet = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]//*[self::p or self::li]").extract()
        info_Erwartungen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][2]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_WirBietenIhnen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][3]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_Publikationsdatum = info.xpath(".//article/footer[@class='inseratfooter']/p[1]/strong/text()").extract_first()

        yield {'Titel': info_Titel,
        'Berufsfelder': info_Berufsfelder,
        'Arbeitspensum': info_Arbeitspensum,
        'Anstellungsverhältnis': info_Anstellungsverhältnis,
        'Arbeitsort': info_Arbeitsort,
        'VerfügbarAb': info_VerfügbarAb,
        'Kompetenzenqualifikation': info_Kompetenzenqualifikation,
        'Aufgabengebiet': info_Aufgabengebiet,
        'Erwartungen': info_Erwartungen,
        'WirBietenIhnen': info_WirBietenIhnen,
        'Publikationsdatum': info_Publikationsdatum}
```